# How can I calculate the difference between two time fields, being the second greatest than the first one?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, date

I'm having trouble getting negative hour as a result. For instance:

```
G           H
08:30       06:00
```

I would like to get a column with the difference between H and G. So I would be filled with -02:30.

When I do a simple calculation, like G2-H2, I get 22:00 as a result.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I saw this post [How to handle Negative Time Delta in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66105/how-to-handle-negative-time-delta-in-google-spreadsheets), but none of them have the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Is your question about Excel or Google Sheets? What are the values shown for each cell in the formula bar?

Comment: **Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you**. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention

> I would like to get a column with the difference between H and G. So I would be filled with -02:30.

The formula **`=H2-G2`** will work fine in Google Sheets once you **format as `Duration`** by going to
`Format` - `Number` - `Duration`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept.